# Switching an Image on Menuitem clicked

Tags: android

I Have a Menu with Images and want to change another imageView on my Fragment to the image from the clicked Menuitem.
At the Moment i change the Image to the first one, because i dont know how to handle the situation without an id. Would be nice when you help me to give them an id or any other solutions.

```
 public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

        HorizontalScrollMenuView menu;
        ImageView imageView;


        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

            menu = (HorizontalScrollMenuView)view.findViewById(R.id.menu);
            imageView =(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


            initMenu();


            return view;
        }



        private void initMenu() {
            menu.addItem("One",R.drawable.ic_one);
            menu.addItem("Two",R.drawable.ic_two);
            menu.addItem("Three",R.drawable.ic_three);
            menu.addItem("Four",R.drawable.ic_four);
            menu.addItem("Five",R.drawable.ic_five);


            menu.setOnHSMenuClickListener(new HorizontalScrollMenuView.OnHSMenuClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onHSMClick(MenuItem menuItem, int position) {

                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.**`This should be the Icon from selected Menuitem`**);

                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to give an id on every menu.addItem

Comment: I suggest that you read the official Android tutorials about menus. Start by looking on http://developer.android.com. `HorizontalScrollMenuView` is not a standard Android class, so you will get very little help trying to use it.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `MenuItem`. There should be a method to get its image resource.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#getIcon()

Comment: Thats the Problem. Normaly i create a menufile which contains items, giving them an Id.

Comment: So do it the way you normally do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now try this updated class

This should work fine, Try this and let me know if you have any question

```
 public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

    HorizontalScrollMenuView menu;
    ImageView imageView;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        menu = (HorizontalScrollMenuView)view.findViewById(R.id.menu);
        imageView =(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        initMenu();


        return view;
    }
    class MyMenu {
        public String title;
        public int imageRes;

        public MyMenu(String title, int imageRes) {
            this.title = title;
            this.imageRes = imageRes;
        }
    }

    private void initMenu() {
            List<MyMenu> myMenus = new ArrayList<>();
            myMenus.add(new MyMenu("One", R.drawable.ic_one));
            myMenus.add(new MyMenu("Two", R.drawable.ic_two));
            myMenus.add(new MyMenu("Three", R.drawable.ic_three));
            myMenus.add(new MyMenu("Four", R.drawable.ic_four));
            myMenus.add(new MyMenu("Five", R.drawable.ic_five));

            for (MyMenu myMenu: myMenus) {
                menu.addItem(myMenu.title,myMenu.imageRes);
            }


        menu.setOnHSMenuClickListener(new HorizontalScrollMenuView.OnHSMenuClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onHSMClick(MenuItem menuItem, int position) {

              imageView.setImageResource(myMenus.get(position).imageRes);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Update**

**Another method :**

You should try this and check that getIcon() work well or not
if that works fine this is a minimal solution just change on click listener

```
        menu.setOnHSMenuClickListener(new HorizontalScrollMenuView.OnHSMenuClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onHSMClick(MenuItem menuItem, int position) {
        if (menu.getItem(position).getIcon() != null)
            imageView.setImageDrawable(menu.getItem(position).getIcon());

            }
        });
```

in this method no need for MyMenu class (as point raised by @Code-Apprentice)

Comment: What is `myMenus`?

Comment: MyMenu is a pojo class with purpose to hold and retrieve the data

Comment: Works fine. Thank you

Comment: Why create `MyMenu` when you already have `MenuItem` which already stores this data?

Comment: Good point! but this was an idea you can implement it any way